# Ruby - is 2am on any date later than 10pm on any date (TRUE)

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, time

I'm trying to compare times without dates and finding it to be very challenging. Basically I'm taking a record's `created_at` and trying to say, regardless of date, is it later than 10pm? If so, take certain action.

Note: Times are stored in my db in UTC, and I only care about Pacific, so any time I retrieve first has to be converted to Pacific.

Example:

```
#1) User makes a request at 2am Pacific Time on 10/10/14, this is the result:
  @rentalrequest.created_at => Wed, 22 Oct 2014 10:03:48 UTC +00:00 
  @rentalrequest.created_at.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)") => Wed, 22 Oct 2014 03:03:48 PDT -07:00 

# Code evaluates whether or not the Pacific Time of creation was later than 10pm. This is where I struggle, so I put the failed options below

#2a) Compare time to a Time object set to 10pm: DOESN'T WORK BECAUSE TIME PARSE ADDS TODAY'S DATE, EVEN THOUGH THE RIGHT COMPARISON WOULD HAVE BEEN TO COMPARE TO 10pm THE DAY BEFORE
  @rentalrequest.created_at.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)").strftime('%H:%M:%S') > Time.parse("22:00:00") => false, since Time.parse("22:00:00") evaluates to => 2014-10-22 22:00:00 -0700 

#2b) Compare only times by using strftime: DOESN'T WORK BECAUSE NOW IT'S A STRING COMPARISON
  @rentalrequest.created_at.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)").strftime('%H:%M:%S') > "22:00:00" => false 

#2c) Compare strftimes that are converted again to time variables: DOESN'T WORK FOR SAME REASON AS 2a
  @rentalrequest.created_at.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)").strftime('%H:%M:%S').to_time > Time.parse("22:00:00").strftime('%H:%M:%S').to_time => false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you want is to compare the hour, so stop comparing entire times and *compare the hour*:

```
@rentalrequest.created_at.hour > 22
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work since the first part will return 2 which is not greater than 22. But this made me realize I can just do `@rentalrequest.created_at.hour < 8 || @rentalrequest.created_at.hour > 22` Thanks!

Comment: @james It will return a number between 0 and 23. If you're after 10pm, you want `22`.

Answer (score 1):

This finds the time between 10pm and midnight

```
@time = @rentalrequest.created_at.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
@time < @time.end_of_day and @time > (@time.end_of_day - 2.hours)
```

---

### Answer

This takes you four hours back.  And compares the 4 hour window between 6pm and 10pm... which four hours forward is 10pm and 2am.  You could do two hours as an alternative.  Just know that `end_of_day` is 1 second before midnight.

```
@time = @rentalrequest.created_at.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
@four_earlier = @time - 4.hours - 1.second
if @four_earlier < (@four_earlier.end_of_day - 2.hours) and @four_earlier > (@four_earlier.end_of_day - 6.hours)
  # do something
end
```